# Limit with Chosen.js dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I used `chosen.js` and have multiple selection dropdown. I want to limit of 4 selection from multiple option with alert message.

I tried with normal dropdown it`s work fine but with chosen.js It's not work.

There is inbuilt option `$(".chzn-select").chosen({ max_selected_options: 4 });`
but it is not given alert message when reach maximum limit.

**How to set limit of maximum 4 option with chosen.js?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an event which gets triggered when `max_selected_options` is reached
you can use it like

```
$('.chzn-select').on('chosen:maxselected', function(obj) {
    do_something();
});
```

I havent tested this.

**[Documentation Here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#limit-selected-options-in-multiselect)**